# Dataframe: Split data only after 2 new line characters

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

So I have a sample data:

```
one
two
three


four
Bob
five
six


seven
eight
nine


eleven
twleve
Bob
thirteen


fourteen
fifteen
sixteen
```

I want to load this data in dataframe such that it'll add data to the new line only when it comes across two or more new line characters.
And then if the block(row) in dataframe contains "Bob", drop that row

Comment: You can split strings on substrings, not just single characters, so `s.split("\n\n")`.

Comment: you should also provide a sample output.